# Is there an Excel Comment Activate or Selection Event?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel Comments to store some information that I want to allow the user to edit using a form.  I want to pre-populate the form with the text contained in the Comment when the user selects the Comment.  I can do this  when the user selects the cell with the red tab (when the Comments are hidden) using the SheetSelectionChange event.  But is there a way to do this when the Comments are shown and the user clicks inside the Comment box?

I can't find any events associated with Comments in the help.  Are there any Comment Events exposed to VBA?  Or can I do this with some Cell or Sheet event?  I tried putting a MsgBox inside the SheetSelectionChange Event to show the Target.ActiveCell, but when I select a Comment, I'm not getting a response, so it seems like when selecting a Comment, it is not associated with a sheet.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Comments, like most Shapes, do not generate a hit on the SelectionChange event.  Unlike many Shapes, you can't even assign a macro to Comments.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there are any events for comments.

However you could use the SelectionChange Event on the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Target.Comment Is Nothing) Then MsgBox Target.Comment.Text
End Sub
```

To use within your Form:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)        
    If Not (Target.Comment Is Nothing) Then
         frmYourForm.Show
         frmYourForm.txtComments = Target.Comment.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Yes, this works if the user clicks on a cell containing the comment when the comments are hidden.  I had that part working.  But when the user has comments shown and clicks within the comment box itself, it doesn't seem to trigger a SelectionChange event because they aren't really selecting a cell on a sheet.  I put a MsgBox statement inside the SelectionChange and it doesn't show when I click inside a comment box.  But Excel must somehow know when you click within a comment, which cell the comment belongs to because it shows the cell in the status bar.

Comment: But there isn't an event associated with it...  You'd have to trigger an event another way.