# Conditional Formatting When a Comments Added

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cell (A5: Z50).
A, C, E, G, H cell colour was set to "Light Blue" (Done). 
The user will need to make changes or input new data into the remaining cell as and when required.
I want the cells (except the above) to change to "Light Green" (I managed to use Conditional Formatting to set it) when data are input/keyed in.
and When a comment is added, I want the cell colour to change to "Light Red".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no event I'm aware of that is triggered by adding a comment to a cell.

Comment: How about using a VBA code instead of conditional format?

Comment: This could be a start for you. [How To Highlight All Cells With Comments In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2254-excel-highlight-cells-with-comments.html)

Comment: Thanks, Wizhi. I have google and the link provided actually doesn't meet my requirement.

Comment: But you can use the link provided by @Wizhi along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305234/is-there-an-excel-comment-activate-or-selection-event) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101227/how-to-trigger-vba-code-after-adding-a-comment) as a *starting point* to get what you want.

Comment: @DerrickLim what doesn't "meet your requirements"?  Please show the code you tried and what's not working. (See how to create a [mcve])

Answer (score 0):

Managed to add a function and applied the conditional format to my worksheet. 
This will help in solving 2 Conditional Format set.

1. Cell colour will be changed to Green when Text keyed in.
2. Cell colour will be changed to Another Colour when comments added.

   ```
   Function IsComm(CellComm As Range) As Boolean
   Application.Volatile
   IsComm = False
   If Not CellComm.Comment Is Nothing Then IsComm = True
   End Function
   ```